# Get password for a user returns undefined using node js express js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to implement a use case where users can request to check his password by providing username.
Issue: Node js back-end app returns result before query is complete. I have checked articles explaining async aspect of javascript. However, I am still unsure if the solutions can be applied when there is a rest call involved in between.

High level flow:

1. Front-end js calls rest api(node.js application) with username to get password
2. Node app calls DB to get password
3. Returned password is displayed on front end

Code:

Front-end:

```
function getPassword() {//Called by clicking button on ui
var username = 'testuser'; //hardcoding for simplicity
  $.ajax({
    url: urlWhereNodeJsAppIsHosted,
    error: function(password) {
      console.log('error' + JSON.stringify(password));
    }, success: function(data) {
      console.log('success' + JSON.stringify(password)); // Displaying on console for now
    }
  });
}
```

Back-end(Node js app):

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'dbuser',
    password: 'dbuserpassword',
    database: 'dbname'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {console.log(err);}
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/verify', (req, res) => {
  var username = req.query.username;
  var password = 'noresult';
  connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM userpassword where user=?, ${[username]}', 
    function(err, rows, fields) {
      password = extractpasswordfromrows(rows);//iterate and get result
    }
  );
  console.log(connection.threadId); //Value is not undefined
  res.send(200, { success: password });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Database:

```
userpassword(user, password) table with existing data.
```

I am new to javascript as well as thinking asynchronously. Please help with your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at promises...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sends `password` outside the success callback without waiting for the query to complete. Try

```
app.get('/verify', (req, res) => {
var username = req.query.username;
var password = 'noresult';
connection.query(
 'SELECT * FROM userpassword where user=?, ${[username]}', 
 function(err, rows, fields) {
   password = extractpasswordfromrows(rows);//iterate and get result
   res.send(200, { success: password }); // Ok, have password here
   }
 );
 // Not Ok, don't have password here
 console.log(connection.threadId); //Value is not undefined
});
```

I haven't attempted to put in check code to verify that the `err` parameter in the call back is not truthy, even if logically seen as impossible.

For general treatment of coding against this error, see ["How do I return the result from an asynchronous call"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5217142).

**Processing results outside the callback**

To avoid nesting code, callback code can resolve or reject a newly created promise depending on processing results, with result and error handling functions attached to the promise using its `then/catch` methods.

Alternatively in Express you can supply multiple callbacks (middleware functions) to [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.get) and use `next` calls to advance to the next middleware function if and when required. As an example based on the post (compiled but not tested):

```
app.get('/verify', 

  (req, res, next) => {
    var username = req.query.username;
    connection.query(
      'SELECT * FROM userpassword where user=?, ${[username]}', 
       function(err, rows, fields) {
         if( err) {
           res.status(500).send("no result");
         }
         else {
           res.locals.rows = rows;
           next();
         }
       }
     );
  },

  (req,res) => {
     const password = extractpasswordfromrows(res.locals.rows); //iterate and get result
     res.send(200, { success: password });
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to get the result if I moved the res.send inside callback as suggested. If I keep at both places(inside callback and at original place as in problem), I get initialization value of password('noresult'). Can you help explain why res/result is not sent back immediately if its being updated from async function. I thought once any async function is called(connect.query here), code execution will move to subsequent lines and as here we have no further lines it will exit from app.get(/verify, ...) call with empty res.

Comment: If it helps, `connection.query` is _not_ an asynchronous function: it returns synchronously after initiating the query but before its completion. The callback is only called after the query has actually completed. See updated post about placing the `res.send`outside the callback.